# hyperref and \renewcommand\appendix

Tags: hyperref

`hyperref` messes up with `\renewcommand\appendix`. This even tho `\appendix` is renewed *exactly* as it is defined in `report.cls` (and works with `hyperref` !)

The problem: .toc file 4th entry of `\contentsline` changes (i.e links go wrong).

Without redefining `\appendix` .toc file is

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chap}{2}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {A}App}{3}{appendix.A}
```

As `\appendix` is redefined, .toc file becomes

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chap}{2}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {A}App}{3}{chapter.1}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\appendix{\par
%  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
%  \setcounter{section}{0}%
%  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
%  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
%\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chap}
\appendix
\chapter{App}
\end{document}
```

Why? And how to fix?

Comment: The `hyperref` package redefines a lot of LaTeX internals. Problems are usually avoided by loading it at the end of your preamble. However, in this case your redefinition will be overwritten if you do that. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}` after your `renewcommand` will work -- well, Ian Thompson just made a quicker statement ;-)

Comment: The problem is, that the chapter number is reset to zero within the `\appendix`, leading to the same hyperlink anchor `chapter.1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `hyperref` already fixes `\appendix` by prepending `\appendix` to fix the anchor names. Your redefinition of `\appendix` throws the fix away.
Therefore the redefinition, not `hyperref` is faulty.

Options:

- Redefine `\appendix` *before* package `hyperref`, because `hyperref` redefinition is defensive and keeps the current meaning of `\appendix` in the redefined `\appendix`.
- If `\appendix` should be redefined *after* package `hyperref` or any other package that defines/redefines `\appendix`, then it should be defined in a defensive way, e.g. via patch commands of package `etoolbox`. Or you need to put the additions of `hyperref` into the new definition of `\appendix`.

Answer (score 1):

[This is perhaps not a full solution, but too long for a comment...]

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve as in your MWE the pdf file, with the `\renewcommand` commented out, hyperref is doing the right thing. Presumably you want to redefine `\appendix` so that it does something different to what is described in the comments. In which case, rather than looking at the standard definition of `\appendix` from `report.cls` you should look at `hyperref`'s definition of `\appendix`, which is the following:

```
\def\appendix{%
  \ltx@IfUndefined{chapter}{%
    \gdef\theHsection{\Hy@AlphNoErr{section}}%
  }{%
    \gdef\theHchapter{\Hy@AlphNoErr{chapter}}%
  }%
  \xdef\Hy@chapapp{\Hy@appendixstring}%
  \HyOrg@appendix
}
```

Note that, according to hyperref.sty, `\HyOrg@appendix=\appendix`. So, rather than modifying `\appendix` you should change `\HyOrg@appendix`. For example, if you use

```
\renewcommand\HyOrg@appendix={\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
```

then the pdf file is now correct. Depending on what you are trying to achieve you may also need to modify the hyperref commands above as well.