# Adding the word "Appendix" to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, appendices

I'm working on the layout oy my master's thesis and would like the TOC to have the word "Appendix" added. I'm working in the `memoir` class and right now the TOC is as follows:

```
1 Test
A Python Code
```

I Would like to have it say:

```
1 Test
A Appendix: Python Code
```

A minimal example of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,oneside,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
%%Chapterstyle%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\if@twocolumn
\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else 
\@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter*{\contentsname}%
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
\@starttoc{toc}%
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\makeatother 
\makeatletter
\ChTitleAsIs
\ChNameAsIs
\ChTitleVar{\huge\rm\centering}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{-20\p@}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{-20\p@}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\DOTI}{\vskip 80\p@}{\vskip 40\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\DOTIS}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip 0\p@}{}{}
\makeatother
%% 

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newpage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}  
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Content} 
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test}
\appendix
\chapter{Python Code}
\end{document}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit. Sorry I'm still new at Latex. This should work as MWE right?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but because nobody can compile the code you provide, this isn't really MWE... You might want to keep it very simple: remove all packages which isn't related to the toc, remove every \input and keep only the needed `\appendix`, `\chapter`, `\section`. It might be better to put your code inside code flag ! :)

Comment: Why not type `\chapter{Appendix: Python Code}` or have a look at the `\part` command.

Comment: @albert You should *never* add `Appendix` manually as in `\chapter{Appendix: Python Code}`. That’s bad practice.

Comment: @RuixiZhang I agree that it is not nice, but this means, according to me, that you are saying that 'A Appendix: Python Code' is not nice, as OP requested. The word `Appendix` is just a word. I would use a construct with `\part` and not repeat the word `Appendix` either (similar accounts for the word `Chapter`). When I would do it I would write on the first line 'Appendix A'  and on the / a next line the title of the appendix.

Comment: @albert also if you do it like that the chapter style would write. Appendix A: Appendix Python Code.

Comment: That would look really horrible. So you want to have instead of 'Appendix A:' the version with 'A Appendix:'. Looks like a redefinition of the `\appendix` command (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198986/hyperref-and-renewcommand-appendix NOTE I didn't look deeper into it yet!).